# Set modification time failed

Tags: ftp, save

### Since Aptana 3, first version, I always get this message when I want to save a file (I work over FTP):

### "Problem Occurred"

Set modification time failed

### finename.php: Invalid argument

And in the log:
ftp> MFMT 20110826092808 filename.php
501 filename.php: Invalid argument

I don't have the right to change the timestamp of my files on the server, because it is changed automatically. Maybe you should insert an option where I can disable this feature.

Thanks!

Comment: I too am having this error I am wondering if my Server's FTP settings are somehow to blame? I am using EC2 server on Amazon with an Xammp install. I am using Aptana plug in for Eclipse as my main FTP/editor and everytime i save a file all though the file will save properly i get the error: Set modification time failed <br/>
< filename >: Operation not permitted.

Comment: same problem here, can someone please start a bounty?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm working in a office where, for a same project and server, some have this error coming up at each upload and others don't...

Comment: does anyone have solution? this is annoying